# how to runnable image using handler

Tags: android, image, stream, handler, runnable

i am newbie and i have a question, i want to runnable image with function handler, but i am failure,
like what code to runnable image on this code ? can help me with this problem ?

```
Intent intent = getIntent();

 String url= intent.getStringExtra("URL");
tombol2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
Drawable d1=LoadImageFromWebOperations(url);
iv.setImageDrawable(d1);

}
private Drawable LoadImageFromWebOperations(String url)
        {
             try
             {
                 InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();
                 Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src name");
                 return d;
        }catch (Exception e) {
                 System.out.println("Exc="+e);
                 return null;
             }  
        }
   }
```

Comment: do you get force close does your app crash?

Comment: If i given code handler on inside code i getting error, i don't know how to make that image can be runnable

Comment: you are not doing it right. if you are getting from url you should use a thread or asynctask

Comment: But how ? I not understand using asyntask, can you tell me ?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html. why not check the docs and if you don't understand then comeback and ask again

Comment: Ok i will check, sorry because new learn android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It fixed, just give this runnable before LoadImageWebOperations

```
runnable = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                LoadImageFromWebOperations(d1);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.getStackTrace();
            }
            new Handler().postDelayed(runnable, 10000);
        }
    };
    new Handler().postDelayed(runnable, 10000);     
}
```

Comment: why would you answer your question when i have answered already and it works for you. is it not duplicating? and also you are creating two handlers.

Comment: it's working, it's not duplicating, it's okay with two handler

Comment: you don't require two handlers

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Handler use it like below.

But i see you are doing Network related operation on the ui thread which is not possible post honeycomb. You must use a thread or asynctask. You will get `NetworkOnMainThreadException`

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html

I suggest you use `thread` or `AsyncTask`

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

```
Handler m_handler;
Runnable m_handlerTask ;  
m_handler = new Handler();   
m_handlerTask = new Runnable()
{
  @Override 
  public void run() { 

    // do something  
    m_handler.postDelayed(m_handlerTask, 1000);    

  }
  };
 m_handlerTask.run();
```

Comment: maybe you have another answer for me ?